# how to send in app request in windows phone 8.1

Tags: notifications, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I'm building an application where a user could send in requests(invites sort of) to other specified users.Once an invitee receives an invite,he/she could accept or decline the request.Then the invitee's response is then sent to the inviter as  a message and recorded in a separate table in azure mobile service. Any idea how this use case could be achieved using windows phone 8.1 and azure mobile service?